# Keypad hiding Custom titlebar (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using custom titlebar in my app, When user clicks on editext for entering text keyboard opens and its hiding titlebar ...

This is my main xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikesHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You both like Harry"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutInterest"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader"
    android:divider="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
</ListView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutInterest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutCheckBox"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/etCommonInterest"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="eg:- Music,Friend,Old."
     android:textSize="15sp"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
     android:paddingRight="20dp"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     android:textStyle="italic"
     />

 </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutCheckBox"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_above="@+id/Status"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <CheckBox android:id="@+id/mCheckBox"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:checked="false"
          android:visibility="gone"/>
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvAddInterest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Find stranger with common interest."
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    />

      </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/form"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btStopStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
        android:textSize="14dp" />


    <EditText android:id="@+id/ChatBoxText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="type message..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btSendText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/form"
    android:text="Send"
    android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my manifest .I have also changed here but still custom title bar going to invisible .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.randomchat"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/TitleBarTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`?

Comment: Omg You are fabulous . thank you and also to Stackoverlow ... love you all